# Quick help - CodeIgniter routing

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

Need a quick hand on setting custom route for my project.

the code works without any reoute definition as

```
 http://myblog.local/posts/categories/show/1
```

but I want to access it as following;

```
 http://myblog.local/posts/1
```

and I've changed my route as following;

```
 $route['posts/(:any)'] = 'posts/categories/show/$3';
```

But my route declaration seems not working,  please help me where i am doing the mistake

Answer (score 1):

```
$route['posts/(:num)'] = 'posts/categories/show/$1';
```

Because you have only 1 segment (the first) to match: **$1**
And the segment must be a number: **(:num)**
(:any) will work too.

Comment: That did't help mate, i am getting 404

Comment: try ``$route['test'] = 'posts/categories/show/1';`` if that wont work, you have another problem..

Comment: all sorted, my issue was, in the controller   $this->uri->segment(); thank you folks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$route['posts/(:num)'] = 'posts/categories/show/$1';
```

also in config file
make it blank
    $config['index_page']='';

hope this might work.